# Python encryption unicode error when converting from Python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycrypto, python-unicode

I found some code which I want to incorporate into my Python encryption program. It should encrypt the files in the code's same directory, and I want it to target a directory. But, it's written in Python 2 and when I change around some code to fit Python 3, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/FyleCript/Dev Files/encryption.py", line 77, in <module>
    encrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), str(Tfiles))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py", line 88, in new
    return SHA256Hash().new(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py", line 75, in new
    return SHA256Hash(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py", line 72, in __init__
    HashAlgo.__init__(self, hashFactory, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.update(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py", line 69, in update
    return self._hash.update(data)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

But the code works perfectly in Python 2. I have tried looking for similar questions on SO and Googling, but no help.

---

Code:

```
def encrypt(key, filename):
        chunksize = 64 * 1024
        outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), "(encrypted)"+os.path.basename(filename))
        filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
        IV = ''
 
        for i in range(16):
                IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))
       
        encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
 
        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
                with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
                        outfile.write(filesize)
                        outfile.write(IV)
                        while True:
                                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                               
                                if len(chunk) == 0:
                                        break
 
                                elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:
                                        chunk += ' ' *  (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))
 
                                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
 
 
def decrypt(key, filename):
        outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), os.path.basename(filename[11:]))
        chunksize = 64 * 1024
        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
                filesize = infile.read(16)
                IV = infile.read(16)
 
                decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
               
                with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
                        while True:
                                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                                if len(chunk) == 0:
                                        break
 
                                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))
 
                        outfile.truncate(int(filesize))
       
def allfiles():
        allFiles = []
        for root, subfiles, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
                for names in files:
                        allFiles.append(os.path.join(root, names))
 
        return allFiles
 
       
choice = input("Do you want to (E)ncrypt or (D)ecrypt? ")
password = input("Enter the password: ") 

encFiles = allfiles()
 
if choice == "E" or 'e':
        for Tfiles in encFiles:
                if os.path.basename(Tfiles).startswith("(encrypted)"):
                        print("%s is already encrypted" %str(Tfiles))
                        pass
 
                elif Tfiles == os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[0]):
                        pass
                else:
                        encrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), str(Tfiles))
                        print("Done encrypting %s" %str(Tfiles))
                        os.remove(Tfiles)
 
 
elif choice == "D" or 'd':
        filename = input("Enter the filename to decrypt: ")
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
                print("The file does not exist")
                sys.exit()
        elif not filename.startswith("(encrypted)"):
                print("%s is already not encrypted" %filename)
                sys.exit()
        else:
                decrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), filename)
                print("Done decrypting %s" %filename)
                os.remove(filename)
 
else:
        print("Please choose a valid command.")
        sys.exit()
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I have used a Python 2 to 3 tool, but it still didn't work.

Also, could you please fix the directory problem? It isn't necessary, but I would like it.

---

**EDIT:** I have replaced `str` with `bytes` and `bytearray` but it returns the same error.

Comment: Did you try using `bytes` instead of `str`? Python 2 strings are just arrays of bytes; Python 3 strings are Unicode, and as the error message says, they need to be encoded into bytes before doing binary things like encryption.

Comment: @TomZych So, replace all the `str` with `bytes`.

Comment: Your example does not seem to fulfill minimal verifiable criteria.

Comment: The modified code with `bytes` instead of `str` still returns the same error

Comment: You have implicit strings too, e.g. `IV`. I don’t have this package on my computer, can’t experiment easily. I recommend you look at the docs and make sure you’re passing a valid type to `encrypt` and anything else that gives an error, then work backwards until all the types are correct. Note that `bytes` is immutable; use `bytearray` when you need something mutable.

Comment: @TomZych install the package via pip install pycrypto

Comment: No thanks, I’m not that invested in your problem.

Comment: What I would like is for someone to give me some straightforward code or edited parts of my code because the substitution of `str` with `bytes` or `bytearray` doesn't work.

Comment: `chr()` is problematic, too. I would collect the values into a list without `chr()` or any other conversion and then pass that list to `bytes()` when you're done looping.

Comment: @tripleee could I have an example?

Comment: Not in a place where I can test code but `ivlist=[]; for i in range(16): ivlist.append(random.randint(0, 0xFF)); IV=bytes(ivlist)` ... and obviously more elegant with a list comprehension so you can avoid the stupid temporary variable.

Comment: @tripleee If you could please edit my whole code and put it in the answer section so I can make this answer answered

Comment: Feel free to answer this yourself. You can mark it "community wiki" if you'd rather abstain from gaining reputation from it and mark the answer as a community effort. Obviously either way don't hesitate to lift text from my comments if you like.

Comment: @tripleee But I am having trouble putting this code you put into my code.

Comment: So do I, on a mobile device far away from anything with a decent keyboard or screen.

Comment: try looking at the .decode('utf8') and .encode('utf8') string methods (or maybe 'ascii' instead of 'utf8', depending on your files.

Comment: @louic where could I place those

Comment: SHA256.new(s.encode('utf8')).digest()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'password' variable is a string, but `SHA256.new` expects bytes (to allow for unicode, for example). That you need bytes is listed in the [Crypto.Hash.SHA256 documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Hash.SHA256-module.html).

The solution is to encode the password to bytes before hashing. This is almost literally what the error message says (if you know that all strings in python 3 are unicode objects):

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

The solution is for example to encode with utf8 :

```
SHA256.new(password.encode('utf8')).digest()
```

Comment: This works but there's a new error:

`ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long`

Comment: Please start a new question if you want to ask about this, and make sure you provide details and show what you have tried already.