# Python 2 encryption program when converted and run in python 3 returns error

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, pycrypto

> **This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350462/python-encryption-unicode-error) question. Please do not mark this question as a duplicate for it has a different error I need to fix.**

TL;DR for the link:

So I was asking about a Unicode error in python for my encryption program and someone told me to just encode the password in utf-8 and it worked.

---

Now I have a second problem, where it says that the IV isn't 16 bytes, so I checked this by putting `print(len(IV))` after the IV and after running 3 tests it only returns 16 once, in the middle of the printed characters, and the end character is greater than 16 (eg: 37, 35, 28, etc.).

How could I fix this so that the IV always returns 16 bytes?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/FyleCript/Dev Files/encryption.py", line 77, in <module>
    encrypt(SHA256.new(password.encode('utf-8')).digest(), str(Tfiles))
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/FyleCript/Dev Files/encryption.py", line 17, in encrypt
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 94, in new
    return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 59, in __init__
    blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", line 141, in __init__
    self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long
```

Code:

```
def encrypt(key, filename):
        chunksize = 64 * 1024
        outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), "(encrypted)"+os.path.basename(filename))
        filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
        IV = ''

        for i in range(16):
                IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))

        encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
                with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
                        outfile.write(filesize)
                        outfile.write(IV)
                        while True:
                                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                                if len(chunk) == 0:
                                        break

                                elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:
                                        chunk += ' ' *  (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))


def decrypt(key, filename):
        outFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filename), os.path.basename(filename[11:]))
        chunksize = 64 * 1024
        with open(filename, "rb") as infile:
                filesize = infile.read(16)
                IV = infile.read(16)

                decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

                with open(outFile, "wb") as outfile:
                        while True:
                                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                                if len(chunk) == 0:
                                        break

                                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))

                        outfile.truncate(int(filesize))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I noticed: `if choice == "E" or 'e'` will always be true.  Instead do `if choice in ( "E", 'e')`

Comment: We don't need to see your entire program, just the minimal amount required to reproduce the issue. There's a *lot* that can be trimmed out.

Comment: Do not use `os.random()` when doing crypto, use [`Crypto.Random()`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Random-module.html) instead. Check [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212550/7553525) to see how to do it properly, it also shows differences between Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's take a look at what `IV` may consist of:

```
IV = ''

for i in range(16):
    IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))
```

Let's see how many bytes a character from `range(0, 0xff)` consumes:

```
>>> [len(chr(i).encode()) for i in range(0, 0xff)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

And this is the source of the problem: you're assuming each character is *one* byte long, but that's not the case.

You can generate a random IV of N bytes with the following code:

```
import os

N = 16
IV = os.urandom(N)
```

Another issue in your code is that you're opening all your files in `'rb'` mode, which stands for "read binary", but attempting to write to it instances of `str`, like your `IV`. That won't work because in this mode you're only allowed to read and write `bytes`, not `str`. In my solution for calculating the `IV` this issue completely disappears.

Comment: So how do I solve the next error:
 `chunk += ' ' *  (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str`? If I put a `b` in front of  it, the encrypted file says it has bytes, but when i open it in the text editor, the file is blank.

Comment: @TrooperZ, you should read about the usage of `bytes` in Python 3 and how this is different from `str`. If a _text_ editor shows you something that looks empty, don't trust it and open your file in a hex editor.

Comment: But in python 2, it shows odd characters (which means it's encrypted)

Comment: What's the size of the newly generated encrypted file? If it's zero bytes, then it is empty indeed.

Comment: it's MUCH bigger (a 3.4 kb to 6.8)

Comment: So, if the size of the new file is not zero, that file is, obviously, not empty. A text editor may show garbage or may not show anything at all (because not all characters are printable). To see the actual bytes of the encrypted file, just do `print(open(your_file, 'rb').read())` or open the file in a hex editor.

Comment: but theres also another issue: when i try to decrypt, it says its already decrypted (sorry for grammar issues im rushing)

Comment: If you have other issues with your code, feel free to ask another question. Please try to fix this yourself first and don't forget to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You have not converted your `IV` string to a byte string. In Python 3 `str` is not a byte string, but a character string. `str` is abstracted away from the concept of how characters are represented as bytes.

You'll need to convert your `IV` variable (and perhaps others, I haven't checked) to be instances of `bytes`. It's also a bit easier to make your bytestring in Python 3.

```
random_byte_list = [random.randrange(256) for _ in range(16)]
IV = bytes(random_byte_list)
```